# How to use AngularJS's several ajax call($http) to request data from a single php file?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ajax

I'm trying to use several AngularJS's ajax call to call a single php file to get different json data accordingly, below is my code:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('myphp.php',{key: "main1"}).then(function (response){
      console.log(response);
      //do something
    });
    $http.get('myphp.php',{key: "main2"}).then(function (response){
      //do something
    });
 });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<header>
 <!-- AngularJS-->
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      <div id="main1">
        </div>
      <div id="main2">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In myphp.php file I have:

```js
<?php
if (isset($_GET["key"])) {
    if ($_GET["key"]=="main1") {
     $url1 = 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php';
     $content = file_get_contents($url1);
     echo $content;
    }
    else if ($_GET["key"]=="main2") {
     $url2 = "blabla"
     $content2 = file_get_contents($url2);
     echo $content2;
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to differentiated different ajax calls and try to get correct data from the counterpart ajax call from php by sending a value while calling myphp.php.

The problem is,,,,it won't work, I'm guessing that my syntax is messed up, can you guys help? Thank you so much in advance!

This is the result I got:
[image]

I add "var_dump($_GET);" at the top of my php code and this is what I got.
[image]

Comment: At the top of your PHP file, add `var_dump($_GET);`, and then report back the findings of what you get for your XHR result.

Comment: I have, please refer to the edit,thank you.  @cale_b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind folks, I solved it. The syntax is wrong, it should be

```js
$http.get(url, {
    params: { param1: value1, param2:value2, param3:value3...... }
});
```

please refer to :
http://tutorialsplane.com/angularjs-pass-data-to-http-get-request/

Comment: 1 minute late, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in html and angular logic.

In html you declare your ng-app directive before load angular core

```
 <html >
<header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</header>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      <button ng-click="getContent('main1')"> main1</button>
      <button ng-click="getContent('main2')"> main2</button>
      <pre>{{content | json}}</pre>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

we already saw the logic errors in php :)

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["key"])) {
    if ($_GET["key"]=="main1")
        $url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php';
    else if ($_GET["key"]=="main2")  
        $url = "https://www.google.com";

    $content = file_get_contents($url);
        echo $content;
}
?>
```

in angular you call twice the `$http`service without correct parameters.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {


    $scope.getContent = function(key){
        $http.get('myphp.php',{params: {key: key}}).then(function (response){
        $scope.content = response.data;
    });
    }
 });
```

Comment: That's because I send a {key: "main1"} in my ajax call, to differentiated each calls, I'm trying to access these keys in my php, how to do that?

Comment: @ alfredopacino I have, could you help?

Comment: This is not really an answer.  What did you change in your code? Anything? It looks identical - you should add comments to the code where you've made changes that explain the specific changes and why.

Comment: This is the very standard anjular js ajax call, if I don't want to differentiated the calls in php(only have one ajax call request to php), it works perfectly, the problem now lays at the fact that my code cannot pass"if ($_GET["key"]=="main1") " this if statement, I don't know what more code should I add...